# ScrollViewer prevent MouseWheel Handling on certain conditions

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I have a Canvas inside a ScrollViewer. I am handling the Mousewheel on my Canvas, e.g. when Ctrl is pressed it will zoom in or out, when shift is pressed, the ScrollViewer will scroll horizontally, etc.
This is all fine as long as the ScrollViewer does not have the ability for vertical scrolling. When more objects are on my canvas it will have this ability, thus bugging my custom handlers, it will always also scroll vertically, but if any of my modifiers are being used (Ctrl, Shift) I want to prevent the default scrollbar scrolling.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you set the event as handled in your custom handlers?

Comment: Actually no, but that did the trick. Didn't think of this simple solution to be honest...